# Remove sequential <br> in div filled by CMS users via rich text editors

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, rich-text-editor, removechild

I have div-area which is filled by CMS users and sends data via a rich text editor. How can I remove sequential **br** tags more than two in a `<div>` using jQuery?

I tried `parent()`, `closest()` but it didn't work.

For example, a CMS user added this HTML code using a rich text editor.

```
<div class="cms-data">
<br>
<span>
<br><br><br><br><br><br>
<a href="/uploads/755/a1.xls" target="_blank">xls</span></a>
<br><br><br>
</span>
<br><br>
</div>
```

**Edit:** I added a class name to the `<div>`, cms-data.

Comment: and what is your desired result? removing `<br>` when there are more than 1 at each place?

Comment: What would `parent` or `closest` have to do with sibling elements? And where's the `div` you mention?

Comment: when i apply parent it removes only one.

Comment: Please show your code what have you already tried.

Comment: *"when i apply parent i removes only one"* What's your starting point? (What element were you looking at when you used `parent`?)

Comment: cant show because it a db data and change to users input, i gave an example...

Comment: The example is invalid markup.

Comment: What should the result look like?

Comment: You could use the CSS to hide/remove subsequent `<br>` tags, like this: `br + br { display: none }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
$("#starting-point").find("br").each(function() {
    if (this.previousSibling && this.previousSibling.nodeName.toUpperCase() == 'BR') {
        $(this).remove();
    }
});
```

That finds all of the `br` elements within the given container (in my case, the element with the `id` `"starting-point"`). Then it loops through them in document order. If we have one that has an immediate previous sibling that's a `br` element, we remove it. We leave it alone if the thing just in front of it is not a `br` element (such as a text node, or a non-`br` element). Note that this doesn't consider `<br> <br>` to be two consequtive elements, because there's a space between them.

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/OXEDUKU/2) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/OXEDUKU/2/edit)

Comment: @minitech: **Ouch** Right. Let's see... :-)

Comment: @minitech: Fixed. That actually made it better anyway. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

DOM!

When a `<br>` is encountered, it is removed. When text or an element is encountered, the next `<br>` is not removed. When an element is encountered, `removeSequentialBR` is called on it, too.

```
function removeSequentialBR(node) {
    var child = node.firstChild;
    var remove = true;

    while (child) {
        if (child.nodeType === 1) {
            if (child.nodeName === "BR") {
                if (remove) {
                    var newChild = child.nextSibling;
                    child.parentNode.removeChild(child);
                    child = newChild;
                    continue;
                }

                remove = true;
            } else {
                remove = false;
                removeSequentialBR(child);
            }
        } else if (child.nodeType === 3 && /\S/.test(child.nodeValue)) {
            remove = false;
        }

        child = child.nextSibling;
    }
}
```

[Here’s a demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/rninty/2LvqA/)

Answer (score -2):

You can use just a regular expression to parse the text and replace all occurences that doesnt fit

```
value = value.replace("/(<br>(\s)*){2,}/","<br><br>");
```

The 1000 is a magical high number, which should include all the `<br>`s; increase this value, if needed. Maybe there is an unlimited value? 0 maybe?

EDIT: Sorry for the bad answer. I fixed the expression. Now it works properly and does find all sets of possible occurences.

Comment: You should test this. As it is, it’s not performing a regular expression replacement, the end of your expression is escaped incorrectly, `[[<br>]` makes no sense, `\[<br>\s]` makes no sense, and why is it `{12,1000}`? 1000 is magical, for sure, but what about 12? Anyway, you can unlimit it with `\s{12,}`…

Comment: Thanks for the unlimited hint. I corrected it. I definetly shot too fast, i'm sorry for that.

Comment: It’s still not a regular expression, I meant `value = value.replace(/(<br>\s*){2,}/g, "<br><br>");`. Also note the `g` flag.