# replace two br with single one jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, line-breaks

Trying to replace two `<br />` with a single one.
Can't get it work. been trying for a couple of hours.

My code:  `thishtml = thishtml.replace(/(?:<br \/\>\s*){2,}/g, '<br>')`

Not working.
Help will be great.

Thanks ahead.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19861184/remove-sequential-br-in-div-filled-by-cms-users-via-rich-text-editors/19862178) may help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Replace multiple <br>'s with only one <br>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17061931/replace-multiple-brs-with-only-one-br)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

`thishtml = thishtml.replace(/(?:<br[^>]*>\s*){2,}/g, '<br>')`

Answer (score 7):

```
$('br').map(function(){

  ($next = $(this).next()).is('br') && $next.remove();

});
```

If your html is not coming from the DOM:

```
$(thishtml).find('br').map( ... )
```

Comment: this is great if he were acting on the DOM.. we don't know where his html is coming from though

Comment: @CrayonViolent then `$(someHtml).find('br').map( ... )`^^

Answer (score 1):

try this :

`.replace(/(?:<\s*br\s*\/?\>\s*){2,}/ig, '<br/>');`

example :

```
var a='sdf sd\
sdf\
sdf\
<br    />\
    <br/>\
  dfbd'
```

result :

`sdf sdsdfsdf<br/>dfbd`

http://jsbin.com/OfEbaCA/6/edit

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
.replace(/(\<br[\s]*\/\>){2,}/g, '<br/>')
```